# Broken site after upgrade via composer from craft 3.37.38

Tags: upgrades, cli

Ran upgrade on my local dev environment.
Seemed to go fine.
Front end site broke and command line updates for craft also error.

My index.php looks like

```
// Set path constants
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';

// Load dotenv?
if (file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load();
}

// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```

CLI craft update gives me:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct() 
...vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php:60
```

I tried downgrading vulcas DotEnv package with no luck.
I then set craft requirement in compose to 3.4.0 but still getting issues loading and updating on CLI, all centered around the Dotenv package.

I did a vanilla install via CLI to check index.php content which are different - AND i noticed composer.json states craft requires php8! Not what the docs say but thats another post.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For vlucas/phpdotenv for 3.4.0, this index.php template should work:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Craft web bootstrap file
 */

// Set path constants
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';

// Load dotenv?
if (class_exists('Dotenv\Dotenv') && file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->load();
}

// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```

For console:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Craft console bootstrap file
 */

// Set path constants
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', __DIR__);
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';

// Load dotenv?
if (class_exists('Dotenv\Dotenv') && file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->load();
}

// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php';
$exitCode = $app->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

It is the `Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->load();` line that allows it to work. Repeat for your craft console file.

You can use the 5.x.x version of vlucas/phpdotenv, but it does require changes to how it is loaded compared to 3.4.x

The Craft CMS starter project provides a 5.x.x example, however this is using a bootstrap include method across both web and console, so you'd have to refactor slightly, but worth it as you don't have to duplicate the same logic in the your console file anymore.

https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/main/bootstrap.php

Comment: There's a separate console file???

Comment: Dotenv is loaded on both the web/index.php and craft file at the root, so you'll need to update both to the necessary Dotenv loading syntax relative to the version in use. If you look at the Craft starter project, they use a bootstrap include file across both so you don't have to duplicate it.

https://github.com/craftcms/craft

Comment: Thanks James. I still don't get what the issue is. I have upgraded another site on local dev with no issues - they have the same craft  and phpdotenv versions in their respective composer.json. Both load frontend fine. But one will not run craft commands on command line. Last ditch attempt i swapped the craft shell file from the working to the broken - hey presto. I realised thats what you call the console file? #still-learning thx

Comment: Yes the craft file at the root is the PHP wrapper file for calling Craft console commands with ./craft. This was likely using the wrong dotenv syntax for loading based on the version.

Comment: Yes that was it

Comment: Note: I just updated from Craft 3.7 to 4.x, and I found it easiest to leave phpdotenv version as 2.4.0, no changes to other files were required.